# Can I add App.xaml back to a Xamarin.Forms project while using Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

The Caliburn.Micro Xamarin.Forms samples (both setup and features illustrate the use of App.cs with no accompanying App.xaml.

I'd like to have an App.xaml file though so I can add in App-level resources into xaml which are now supposed in Xamarin.Forms. Is this possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, I haven't added one afterwards ever and this is untested, but it should work something like this.

The `App.xaml` was introduced later into the Xamarin.Forms packages and templates, probably due to the introduction of the app-level resources you are referring to. But basically, the `App.xaml` isn't different from any other XAML file.

Add a new App.xaml file which looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="YourNamespace.YourClass">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Note that you need to supply your own namespace in the `x:Class="YourNamespace.YourClass"` attribute. Now in the same class that you specify here, which should be in your `App.cs`, make sure the class is marked as `partial` and the `InitializeComponent();` is called in the constructor.

Lastly, make sure that your `App.xaml` file is marked to be an `EmbeddedResource` as build action.

In fact that is everything there is to it.

If you want to link your `App.xaml` and `App.xaml.cs` file so that they are shown as one node in Visual Studio, open your csproj file in a text-editor and find the `<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs" />` node. Edit this to be:

```
<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

While this looks nicer, it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks... I tried something like this once and it for some reason it didn't work. I might've missed something. I'll try this again as soon as possible and get report back whether it worked. Thanks!