# Xamarin: Is it possible to include my font recources in the App.cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

Hi my current xamarin app does not have a global App.xaml file only an App.cs, this is the way I configured it and would like to keep it that way.

Now to the issue, I would like to use some font icons from fontawsome but for this to work I need to define a resourcedictionary which is possible in the xaml file. Right now I am copy pasting the resources to each xaml page I need icons in.

I would like for the resources to work global so is there a way I can convert my code to C# or implement the resources in my global App.xaml file so I do not have to copy/paste it all the time.

Here is the code I use for my resources:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Brands-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" 
          Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Have you tried something so far ?

Comment: Yes googling without result i tried to convert the code to c# but it didn't work at all

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin has updated the way you reference fonts and it's far easier than before.

Now, all you have to do is :

- add your font in an assembly that is added as reference by your iOS and Android projet
- set the build action (file properties) to Embedded resource
- update the AssemblyInfo of the assembly where you've added the fonts
- set the alias name of the font in the FontFamily
- you are good to use those fonts

[image: Here is a picture that show those steps]

Edit :
If you can't upgrade to latest XF, here are the steps (hold tight, it's more complicated) :

1. iOS :

- In your iOS project, under Resources folder, add the fonts as BundleResource
- Edit your Info.plist with this code

  ```
   <!-- Custom fonts -->
   <key>UIAppFonts</key>
   <array>
       <string>Fonts/FontAwesome-Regular.otf</string>
       <string>Fonts/FontAwesome-Solid.otf</string>
       <string>Fonts/FontAwesome-Light.otf</string>
   </array>
  ```

2. Android :

- Add the font as AndroidAsset (file properties)

3. Xamarin Forms :

- Create resources that target those fonts in you App.xaml resources

  ```
  <!--#region FONTS-->
  <OnPlatform x:Key="FAR" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Regular.otf#FontAwesome5ProRegular" />
      <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Pro-Regular" />
      <On Platform="UWP" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Pro" />
      <On Platform="Default" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Regular.otf" />
  </OnPlatform>
  <OnPlatform x:Key="FAS" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Solid.otf#FontAwesome5ProSolid" />
      <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Pro-Solid" />
      <On Platform="UWP" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Pro" />
      <On Platform="Default" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Solid.otf" />
  </OnPlatform>
  <OnPlatform x:Key="FAL" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <On Platform="Android" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Light.otf#FontAwesome5ProLight" />
      <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Pro-Light" />
      <On Platform="UWP" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Light.otf#Font Awesome 5 Pro" />
      <On Platform="Default" Value="Fonts/FontAwesome-Light.otf" />
  </OnPlatform>
  <!--#endregion FONTS-->
  ```

4. Use the font (but not with alias) with a StaticResource (remove the space in the code and before Label in the given code : the editor is eating them so I had to add a space to make it visible)

   < Label FontFamily="{StaticResource FAR}" Text="& #xf2bd;" />

Be carefull : it can be hard to find the font path name to use : in the first exemple I gave, Xamarin is doing the work for you. With the old way, you have to find the name yourself (I had some trouble the first time to find the name for each platform). You can find the font name by either installing it on your computer or in the details of the properties of the file.

[image: (See the second picture to find all those steps summarized.)]

/!\ maybe it works with white space in the font name. I don't know why it wouldn't work for me with spaces. So it might not be a requirement to remove the space in the font name.

You can do the same things in code behind for the Xamarin Forms App.xaml part.

Hope it will help you

Comment: my xamarin forms is on an older version this works for 4.6 i think? I am unable to update (tried that) and then the whole app doesnt work anymore. I'm looking for a way to do it on 4.4 do you know any? else ur answer would work perfectly

Comment: @ernie You mean that Nk54's reply can not work on Xamarin.forms 4.4, I test at Xamarin.forms 4.1, it also work fine.

Comment: @Nk54 sorry i went away for bit ill check it out now

Comment: I do not have the app.xaml file

Comment: @ernie Maybe you can try to add App.xaml by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48786114/can-i-add-app-xaml-back-to-a-xamarin-forms-project-while-using-caliburn-micro)

Comment: @ernie you can do the same in CS or the easiest way is to add the app.xaml it's very easy. I can't do all the work for you ^^